# How do you run container commands on ElasticBeanstalk / Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions, amazon-linux-2

I currently have a Laravel application running on ElasticBeanstalk with the following file running a deployment command for me...

.ebextensions/deployment-commands.config

```
container_commands:
    01-run-migrations:
        command: "php artisan migrate --force"
        cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
        leader_only: true
```

I'm trying to update my PHP version to 7.4 so I need to upgrade to an Amazon Linux 2 server.  This command doesn't seem to work on the new Amazon Linux 2 setup so I'm wondering if it will pickup ebextensions anymore and if so do I need to change the cwd?  Basically what do I need to do to get this deployment command to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to update my PHP version to 7.4 so I need to upgrade to an Amazon Linux 2 server.

Not sure what do you mean here, but upgrading from Amazon Linux 1 (AL1) to AL2 may require many more changes then just upgrading php:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

`container_commands` run in staging folder `/var/app/staging`. But you are trying to use different folder `/var/app/ondeck` which may be why you don't see the commands effects.